# In jquery UI drop effect, how can I find the being dragged element?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

In the jquery UI drop effect,how can I find the being draged one?

```
$('#test').droppable({
                drop: function (e,ui) {
                    //$(this) means the drop-container
                    //How can I use the "ui" parameter find the being draged one? 
                    }
                }
            });
```

Like ui.?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ui.draggable` is the element being dragged.

> **Drop (event)**
>   This event is triggered when an accepted draggable is dropped 'over' (within the tolerance of) this droppable. In the callback, $(this) represents the droppable the draggable is dropped on. **ui.draggable represents the draggable**.

[**Documentation**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop)

```
$('#test').droppable({
    drop: function (e,ui) {
        // "ui.draggable" is the dragged element (as a jquery object)
        ui.draggable.addClass('myClass')
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `ui.draggable` is already a jQuery object, so you don't have to call `$()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I use like this to catch draggable element id.

```
$('#test').droppable({
 drop: function (e,ui) {
 var uiId = ui.draggable.attr('id');
   }
});
```